# how to connect form and table in typo3 using xampp server

Tags: mysql, xampp, typo3, typo3-11.x

Can you please explain how to connect a form and table in TYPO33 using xampp server.

I already created a database but don't know how to connect a particular form with a table.

How to connect form with database using xampp server

Are there any tutorials about TYPO3 available?

Comment: There are many scenarios how table data can be used for forms.
A select field could be filled with table data, or a value could be set based on table data, also it's possible to save independent user-data in an individual table. So you have to describe more detailed what you want to do,

Comment: I am just a beginner on typo3. I already installed typo3 using xampp server while installation database is connected with MySQL. As a sample I just created a registeration form on typo3. My need is while I submitting the form, response is to be saved on the MySQL  database. But while I checked on the form finishers, there is only option for the confirmation on submittion. Don't know how to get the response on the mysql database on a particular table.. can you help me for doing

Comment: So which form data (fields) you want to save? Could the be saved in the table fe_users? Or you want to have an own table for the data?

Comment: And please make sure that you use a supported version (11 or 12). You tagged version 6.2, that's out of an kind of support, it's too old.

Comment: Currently I am using typo3 version 11. Fields like name emailid ne needed to save on database. How to connect a form with a table on database

Comment: Basically I already created a table in MySQL database, now I need to connect the front end form to that particular table.. while I checked on the typo3 dashboard, didn't see nothing to connect a table

Comment: please verify the changes I did to your question as I have problems to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a frontend (FE) form where visitors of your website can enter data and you want the input data saved in a table you need to use a `database finisher` ([Concept](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/I/Concepts/Finishers/Index.html#savetodatabase-finisher), [configuration](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/D/FinisherOptions/Index.html#savetodatabase-finisher))

Of course you only can save data to tables known to TYPO3. So it's of no use if you only create a table by hand in your database.
All tables need to be describes in the TCA (TYPO3 Configuration Array). therefore you need to create an extension with all the necessary declarations for the table. This could be done easily with the TYPO3 extension [`Extension Builder`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/extension_builder/)

---

Otherwise you can get official documentation from https://docs.typo3.org/
(Be aware that some pages depend on the TYPO3 version, which you can be select in the dropdown at the top left beyond the document name.)

e.g.

- extension building:
  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Tutorials/Kickstart/Index.html#
- configuration:
  https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/Configuration/Index.html
- configuration of the form extension:
  https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/11.5/en-us/Index.html